# Python bindings: like pants or not?

Tags: python, comments, documentation, swig, manual

I'm working with some collaborators to write up long-form documentation for the Python interface we've added to a particular library. I would call this interface "**Python bindings**", and say "we have written Python bindings for the library". In my mind the bindings are a collection of individual binding items for each piece of the library, only useful together, like a pair of pants.

But some of my collaborators seem to use the singular "**Python binding**", as in "we have written a Python binding for the library". The whole assemblage of pieces to connect our library to Python is together a single binding, and if we hooked it up to another language, like Ruby, that would be another binding. Wikipedia [describes a binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding) in a way that supports this usage.

Which usage is actually more common? Is one a newer phenomenon than the other? What is preferred by major projects?

Note that I am NOT asking what any given answerer prefers, or which usage is "better"; that would be immediately closed as opinion-based. Answers should provide examples of major (Python-community) projects tending to prefer one version or the other (or being more or less split), or cite sources indicating one usage to be more common than the other (or showing that there is no clear consensus).